# How can I be sure that a Library like Pandas is not sending my API Key Secrets to places outside from my Local?

Tags: python, azure, secret-key

Let's say:

- I have my python code in main.py and I am using Pandas
- I am storing my API Key(to some azure service) in a Windows Environment Variable ( `variable name = "AZURE_KEY"` and `variable_value = "abc123abc"`)
- I will import this API Key in main.py using `azure_key = os.environ.get("AZURE_KEY")`

**Question:**
How can I be sure that Pandas Library hasn't sent azure_key's value to somewhere outside my local system?

**Possible Approach:**
I know one way is to go through the entire Pandas module files and understand the source code to see if any fishy stuff is happening , but such an approach is not feasible.

**Note:**
Pandas is just an example for the question.I want to use an API Key within a Streamlit code.
Hence,Please take this question agnostic to the library..

Comment: Most Python libraries are open-source. Other than going over the source code you can't really be sure of anything. Heck, you can't even be sure that Python itself isn't doing something fishy with your keys...

Comment: @DeepSpace Thanks for responding. I just coincidentally edited my question for going through source code as a possible solution lol.... So don't you think storing api keys as windows env variables can provide the protection even if the library had some fishy stuff in it (that stores my api key)

Comment: @newbie101 No, it doesn't provide any protection. Why do you think Pandas couldn't do `os.environ.get` internally? Anyway, the only way to be sure that data isn't sent anywhere is one of: (a) vet all code you're running (b) prevent Python from accessing the network (c) disconnect the machine altogether

Comment: Also, even if you had read all of Pandas, do you trust whoever built the binary Pandas wheel you've installed? If you built it yourself, do you trust the compiler? The trust rabbit hole goes deep: https://www.onceuponscience.com/post/reflections-on-trusting-trust

Comment: @AKX How do you do (b)?

Comment: @KellyBundy Depends on your operating system and environment. On macOS, e.g. https://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html – on Linux, an iptables rule could do it (or running the app in a `--net=none` Docker container!)... on Windows, I suppose Windows Firewall could.

Comment: Feel free to roll it back. But do read the tag usage guidelines, including the ones which say "do not use this."

Answer (score 1):

- For a production system (on a server), you could use a firewall to filter outgoing connections
- For a development system (your machine), you could add restrictions to the "API Key" account (e.g. only access test data, only access systems you really need, etc.)

Comment: What `api_key` account?

Comment: @AKX As I understand the question, he's afraid of loosing an "API Key" secret which probably gives you access to some cloud service.